# Tableau WAMP Data Connector

Tags: websocket, tableau-api, autobahn, crossbar, wamp-protocol

Tableau has several data connectors.  These all seem to use a request/response mechanism that pulls / polls for data updates.

I have a data service that talks WAMP (web application messaging protocol) using crossbar.io (router) and autobahn-python (wamp producer).   Is there a Tableau connector that I could use to consume this service?  Or more generally, does Tableau have a connector that can be used to communicate via web sockets?

Comment: Read about Tableau's web data connector. An API designed for this purpose.

Comment: Crossbar.io contains a REST API bridging service. Maybe you can connect to Tableau using this? - see http://crossbar.io/docs/HTTP-Bridge/

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check out web data connector as well as the crossbar REST API.  From initial read, it appears to still be as an adapter using a request/response as opposed to a publish/subscribe mechanism (i.e. using HTTP POST).  But I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I assume Tableau has a HTTP/REST API where it takes in data supplied to it in the form of HTTP/POST requests with JSON body? If so, this may indeed be a job for the HTTP/REST bridge built into Crossbar.io, One of the things the bridge does is; it can forward WAMP events on a topic as HTTP requests on URLs. The catch is: there are a lot of details to this mapping and forwarding that it might be not enough currently with what we have in terms of knobs and settings for that. We could certainly add stuff there. Let me know how it works .. sounds like an interesting idea!